# Altium PCB Layout : Rectanguler Vias in Altium

Tags: altium, layout

Can we design a rectangular via ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can anyone drill a rectangular hole?

Comment: Vias are made by drilling. You can not drill small rectangular hole with round drill, unless you use much smaller drill, but then it is not a via, it will be a hole :) Why do you need it? Vias are there to provide connectivity, and its shape should not matter. You need to explain your real problem, then we can see if you may have some valuable advice or answer.

Comment: Hello,

I Need to place my PCB on an IC.
I can make it by using a hole but My idea is to make a rectanguler hole or a via from Layer 1 to Layer 2 in a 4 layer board so that, I can use layer 3 and 4 for Routing.
If it is possible then I can shorten my PCB size.

Comment: Why can't you do the same with a round via?

Comment: As I am contacting IC Pins to my board using PADS.
If I use round Vias then my PAD length should  be decreased which I cannot do

Comment: Without a drawings, it's hard to envision what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is possible to have plated cutouts, but they tend to be used for mounting screws or other fixings and are rather large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can design a (nearly) rectangular board cut-out. Simply draw the internal cut-out when you are drawing your board outline, then use "Board Shape -> Define from selected objects" to create the board shape with an internal cut-out. Be aware that the cut-out will be made with a router tool, so you should allow for a non-zero radius (.0465 inches radius is a common size --- consult your fab shop if you want a smaller size) on the inner corners of any cut-out.

If you want to make a cut-out only partially through the board, that's also possible, but you'll need to shop around for a fab shop that will do it, and consider their capabilities carefully. You'll need to allow for

- Non-zero inner radius on the cut-out outline
- Non-zero tolerance on the cut-out dimensions
- Non-zero tolerance on the cut-out depth

You'll communicate your design to the shop with an additional drawing made on a mechanical layer, or with a detail on your fabrication drawing. In Altium, this is often made on the "Drill Drawing" layer. Be sure to provide all the dimensions of the cut-out, along with tolerances in this drawing or detail.

The shop that is able to do this type of design is probably not the lowest-cost shop in the world (or in your market).

Answer (score 2):

Altium has [support for rectangular pads](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Support+for+Rectangular+Pad+Holes), but not rectangular vias.

Answer (score 0):

A via has two pads on both sides of the PCB. The connection between those pads is done by galvanic plating of the drill hole within the pads. As others wrote, the drill hole must be circular. The pads may be round, square or rectangular. A PCB manufacturer is able to mill a rectangular hole, for instance 5 mm wide and 6 mm high with a corner radius of about 1 mm using a standard router tool. The radius may be as small as 0.4 mm using a router with 0.8 mm diameter. But there is no practical way to make holes 0.5 mm wide and 0.6 mm high.

A different thing are blind holes for vias within a multilayer board. Thus a connection between layer 1 and 2 is possible without affecting or drilling layer 3 and 4. With two blind holes from both sides, a connection from layer 1 to 2 and from layer 3 to 4 is possible at the same place of the pcb. A multilayer board with 6 or more layers may even use buried vias between layer 3 and 4. But you should ask your manufacturer about the cost of those high tec boards before.